Let $a,b$ be algebraic over the field $F$, with $\deg(a,F)$ and $\deg(b,F)$ coprime. Is $\deg(a+b,F)=\deg(a,F)\deg(b,F)$? What about $\deg(ab,F)$?
Let $a,b$ be algebraic over the field $F$, such that $\deg(a,F)$ and $\deg(b,F)$ are coprime. Then is $\deg(a+b,F)=\deg(a,F)\deg(b,F)$? What about $\deg(ab,F)$?
I have tried to represent $a,b$ as matrices: let $m=\deg(a,F), n=\deg(b,F), E=F(a,b)$. Then $[E:F]=nm$, with $a^ib^j$ ($0≤i≤m-1,0≤j≤n-1$) be a base. Consider elements in $E$ as $F$-linear transformations and this gives a map $H$ from $E$ to $n\times n$ matrices over $F$. Easy to know that $u$ and $H(u)$ share the same minimum polynomial.  Thus the problem transfers to find the degree of $H(a+b)$. But I just stuck here.

Welcome to MSE. Please read the tutorial on how to format Mathematical expressions. As it is currently written, your question is unreadable in places.

If $a$ is a primitive cubic root of unity (degree $2$) and $b=\sqrt[3]{2}$ (degree $3$), then $ab$ has degree $3$, not $6$.

@ArturoMagidin Got it. Thank you!

The question for sums is answered at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26832/degree-of-sum-of-algebraic-numbers

Have you followed the link, DTK?

@GerryMyerson Yes I do. Thank you for providing that. It's a beautiful conclusion.

Perhaps you'd like to post a summary as an answer to your question.
